# How to change color of my div if check-box is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table that is created based on records from data base. Inside of tbody I have tr that creates each table row. Table row has multiple time slots for same date. I want to change background color of my time block if check box is checked. I got my check box to work, I did test with alert and some text inside. Now I'm trying to change the background color but nothing works in this case that I tried so far. Here is my code:

```
 <cfoutput query="qryTest" group="DateMeeting">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>#DateMeeting#</td>
            </tr>
            <cfoutput>
               <tr class="blockRow">
                  <td>#StartTime#</td>
                  <td>#EndTime#</td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block"></td>
               </tr>
            </cfoutput>
         </tbody>
 </cfoutput>
```

Java script:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var div = $(this).closest('.blockRow');
    $(this).is(":checked") ? div.addClass("red") : div.removeClass("red");
});
```

and my css:

```
.red{
   background-color:red; 
}
```

This is working code that I updated. Problem number one was in html structure of my code. Second If I used document.getElementById('') I was getting only first row chnaged background-color, no matter which row I click on. So I have had to use getElementByClassName. Anyway I decided to use JQuery addClass/removeClass. Thanks everyone for help with this problem.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting

Comment: `$('#blockRow').css("backgroundcolor","red")` should be camelCase: `$('#blockRow').css("backgroundColor","red")`

Comment: In your jQuery call for the CSS change, "backgroundcolor" needs to be exactly like in CSS, "background-color". Idk if that is the problem though

Comment: I'm not getting any error that's the problem, I can't find what is wrong. If I use alert my code gives me text every time I click on check box.

Comment: have you more than one element which ID is `#blockRow` ? In this case, you should use class

Comment: Your problem is that you aren't using the jQuery library, so you can't use jquery functions. See my edition.

Comment: Check that your element does not have a background property, if it has a background property use this one instead background-color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var div = $(this).closest('.blockRow');
    $(this).is(":checked") ? div.addClass("red") : div.removeClass("red");
});

.red{
    background-color:red; 
}

<cfoutput query="qryTest" group="DateMeeting">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>#DateMeeting#</td>
            <cfoutput>
                     <div class="blockRow">
                     <td>#StartTime#</td>
                     <td>#EndTime#</td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block"></td>
                 </div>
            </cfoutput>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</cfoutput>
```

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3s83gj70/2/

This gets the closest blockrow to the current checkbox so should work with more than one instance. Since you can't have 2 elements with the same id I have change blockrow to the class.

If you want to do other things based on the same condition then you can do this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var div = $(this).closest('.blockRow');
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        div.addClass("red");
        //checkbox is checked, do something
    }
    else
    {
        div.removeClass("red");
        //checkbox is not checked, do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a jQuery tag, so it is a reasonable assumption

Comment: How I can set different values for checkbox depends on if my check box is checked or unchecked?

Comment: I have added an edit, you just have to set the values you want when in the right part of the `if else` although, if you post the form when a checkbox is checked the value will be true, if it's not checked the value will be false or not sent at all. If you have to define other values a checkbox probably isn't the right input for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
 $('#blockRow').css("background-color","red")
 ------------------------------^
```

### EDIT

Then you don't include jQuery library. To make pure js make this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfss81sa/

```
 document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Here you are the complete snippet:

```js
  var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  for(var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
<div id="box">
The box
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but you need to adapt to your code. I see you accept another answer, but this code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your html code is a mess. Anyway, generally :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked') {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td:first').css('background', 'red'); 
  } else {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td:first').css('background', 'white');
 }
});
```

Of course, you can narrow the scope of input:checkbox selector.
If it is not the FIRST `<td>` in your `<tr>` then you better assign it a class and get it with it.

NOTE : DOM must be correct `<cfoutput>` cannot be child of `<tr>`; `<div>` cannot have `<td>` as direct child; Incorrect DOM impact javascript traversing.

Comment: You are assuming that jQuery library is included.

Comment: Fairly :) So much simpler.

Comment: This code change color outside of my table.  But at least works onClick. So I guess something is wrong with the tags.

Comment: Probably malstructured html. Show your final html output as this in your example si not a valid html. DOM must be correct.

Comment: I used your code and instead of parents('div') I used parents('tr'). I have one problem, if I click first row all my td's change color. But for all other rows works fine. So I want all td's but first td that holds the date. That is why I used div but that does not work.

Comment: Is it possible to set different values for checkbox depends on if checkbox is checked or not? I'm trying to send value with Ajax, but can not get the right value after I unchecked my checkbox.