# How can I change background of each table data if the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple task manager for myself where if I complete doing something I mark the checkbox and the background of that table data changes, and I read that question too: [How to change color of my div if check-box is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270145/how-to-change-color-of-my-div-if-check-box-is-checked/34270334)
then I wrote something like this:

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="box">
      English<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
    </td>

    <td id="box">
      Math<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
    </td>
    
    <td class="box">
      Physics<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem I am facing is only the first box' background gets changed after checking  any of 3 checkboxes as bellow. I just want each box background to change only when it is checked.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771168/2813224) it's pure CSS, no JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `event.Target` to target the element being checked and then set its `parentNode/s` style. Your `querySelectorAll` returns a ***nodeList***, you can use `nodeList.forEach()` on this function to loop over its list of nodes. Then pass the ***event*** into the `eventListener` and use `event.target` to get the element that is triggering the event.

Also, not sure why you had script tags in the middle of your HTML, no need for that. Place the script either a the bottom of the body or at the top and place a defer attribute. [Read me: Script tags MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

```
// @ the top of the page in the head tag of the document: 
<script defer>//javascript code</script>

// @ the bottom of the page just above the body tag

  <script>//javascript code</script>
  <body>
<html>
```

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
cbs.forEach(item =>
  item.addEventListener('change', e =>
    e.target.checked ?
    e.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "green" :
    e.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"))
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="box">
      English<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
    </td>
    <td id="box">
      Math<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
    </td>
    <td class="box">
      Physics<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to help, feel free to mark as accepted if this did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Change `document.getElementById("box")` to `this.parentElement`; getting the click event target is superfluous.

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Task Achievement</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td id="box">
        English<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
      </td>
      <td id="box">
        Math<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
      </td>
      <td class="box">
        Physics<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code, let me know if it works -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Task Achievement</title>
        <script>
            function myFunction(item) {
                if (item.checked) {
                    item.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else {
                    item.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                }
            }
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td id="box">
                    English<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                </td>
                <td id="box">
                    Math<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                </td>
                <td class="box">
                    Physics<input type="checkbox" name="block" id="block" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's really what I was looking for, thank you so much!!

Comment: Please mark the answer to complete, if it solves your problem, or atleast a thumsup :)